# taxonomy terms view with custom alphabar (for Spanish)

Tags: taxonomy-terms, paging, views

I have a lot of views displaying taxonomy vocabularies with alphabar, the problem is that all the alphabar are by default showing the order for English alphabet, Spanish has ñ and accented letters, at both the alphabar as in the views, words starting with this letters are sent to the back, for instance, alphabar is like this:

- ......w | x | y | z | ñ | á | é | í | ó | ú

the ñ should be placed after n and those letters with accent shouldn't appear, they should be included within the corresponding unaccented letter

same for order in the view, for instance words are ordered like this (fictional words for the example)

- awto
- axma
- aypa
- azor
- años
- aísi
- aóko
- etc.

when correct order should be like this:

- aísi
- años
- aóko
- awto
- axma
- aypa
- azor

Any idea on how to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've been reading some documentation about 
character settings in mysql, and I have found a solution, I don't know if it's the right way for drupal, and it would not interfere with the taxonomy modules at update time in some way, I hope somebody could comment on this....
Anyway I just changed at the taxonomy_term_data table the collation of the "name" field to utf8_spanish_ci