# taxonomy terms view with custom alphabar for not listed language

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views, paging

I could solve just part of my problem, check "[taxonomy terms view with custom alphabar (for Spanish)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/204009/taxonomy-terms-view-with-custom-alphabar-for-spanish)". I'm working with two languages, Spanish and Mapudungun, so I have Spanish > Mapudungun and Mapudungun > Spanish dictionaries. As you can see at the linked issue I could solve my problem at the Spanish > Mapudungun dictionaries, but I have different needs at the Mapudungun > Spanish ones.
In Mapudungun I have sounds represented by two letters or a letter plus an apostrophe: ch | l' | ll | n' | ng | sh | t' | tr | ü . Beside the normal letters, not all of them by the way, for instance, there is no b, no c without h, no h preceded by a c, no j, no q, no v, no x, no z. Actually this is the complete alphabet for Mapudungun:

a | ch | d | e | f | g | i | k | l | l' | ll | m | n | n' | ng | ñ | o | p | r | s | sh | t | t' | tr | u | ü | w | y

So I'm looking for a way to represent those "special" letters in the alphabar and at the same time give the same order to the entrances at the dictionary, I mean, for instance that the n does not mix up with n' and ng and have them independently ordered as they are totally different letters. At this moment I have:

```
na
ne
nga
nge
ngi
ngo
ngu
ngü
ni
no
nu
nü
n'a
n'e
n'i
n'o
n'u
n'ü
```

And I should have:

```
na
ne
ni
no
nu
nü
n'a
n'e
n'i
n'o
n'u
n'ü
nga
nge
ngi
ngo
ngu
ngü
```

Any ideas, thanks